# session tokens not working

Tags: php, forms

I have two identical contact forms with the exception of different STMP information on the backend forms.

What's puzzling me greatly is that when I complete both the forms, and get redirected, on one form, ie, when I choose to go back via browser's button, I still see all the information still on the form. Yet, on the other server, when I go back via browser's back button, the form has refreshed itself.

Any particular reason why the behavior is so consistently different on identical forms yet on different servers?

**EDIT**

(also would like to note that the forms are stripped down versions, ie, I took out the css, jquery stuff, footers, navs, etc. to keep it short and faster to read)

I've decided to include the form from one server, the one that's always showing the contact's information when you hit back. I would like to note that this behavior is extremely consistent, and with the same browser. They're just on different servers. Also, ie, different PHP versions if that makes any difference. And it's PHP-sessions powered pages. Ie, the browser shouldn't be keeping the information, correct?

**Contact Form**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>

<?php
session_start(); //allows use of session variables

if (!isset($_SESSION['token']) && $_SESSION['token'] == $_POST['token']) {

  $token = base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32));
  $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
}

else {
  $token = base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32));
  $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
}

var_dump($_POST, FILE.__LINE__);

?>

<div id="main-container" class="col-xs-12">

  <div>
    <label>* Required fields </label>
  </div>


  <form class="form-horizontal"  method="POST" action="ughAgain.php" id="contactForm">

    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>" />

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="cfirstname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">* First Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input class="form-control"  name="first_name" id="cfirstname" placeholder="First Name" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="clastname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">* Last Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input class="form-control" name="last_name" id="clastname" placeholder="Last Name" type="text">
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="cemail" class="col-sm-2 control-label">* Email</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input class="form-control" name="email" id="cemail" placeholder="Email" type="email">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="cmessage" class="col-sm-2 control-label">* Message</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" placeholder="Please type in your message" name="message" id="cmessage"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey=""></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha" data-rule-recaptcha="true">
  </div>
</div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="Submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Action Form: UghAgain.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

  require_once('recaptchalib.php');
  require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';



  $captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
  $secretKey = "";
  $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secretKey."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$ip);
  $responseKeys = json_decode($response,true);
  if(intval($responseKeys["success"]) !== 1) {

      header('location: url');
 }

else  {


  if ($_POST['token'] == $_SESSION['token']) {

  $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
  $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];


  $mail = new PHPMailer;
  $mail->isSMTP();  
  //$mail->SMTPDebug = 4; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
  $mail->Host = ''; // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
  $mail->Username = '';                 // SMTP username
  $mail->Password = ''; 
  $mail->From = '';
  $mail->FromName = 'Staff';
  $mail->addAddress( $email, $first_name );
  $mail->addAddress( '', 'Staff' );
  $mail->addReplyTo( $email, $first_name );
  $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
  $mail->Subject = 'Hotel Contact';
  $mail->Body = "<table width='600'><tr><td colspan='2' height='20'><p style='text-align:center; font-size:20px; color:#ddd; padding:0px; margin:0px;'>Copy of Your Contact Form</p></td></tr>"
                ."<tr><td colspan='2'  height='80' width='600'><p style='color:#d1502d;font-size:50px;text-align:center;padding:0px; margin:0px;'>Hotel</p></td></tr>"
                ."<tr><td colspan='2'  height='60' width='600' style='text-align:center; color:#606060;font-size:20px;padding:0px; margin:0px;'> Los Angeles, CA </td></tr>"
                ."<tr><td colspan='2'  height='30' width='600' style='text-align:center;'><h3 style='color:#d1502d; '>Come and Explore Little Tokyo in Los Angeles</h3></td></tr>"
                ."<tr><td height='20' width='300'><p style='font-size:20px; color:gray; padding:10px; margin:0px; text-align:right;'>Your First Name: </p></td><td height='20' width='300'> <p style='font-size:20px; color:gray; padding:10px; margin:0px;'>$first_name</p></td></tr>"
                ."<tr><td height='20' width='300'><p style='font-size:20px; color:gray; padding:10px; margin:0px; text-align:right;'>Your Last Name: </p></td><td height='20' width='300'><p style='font-size:20px; color:gray; padding:10px; margin:0px;'>$last_name</p></td></tr>"
                ."<tr><td height='20' width='300'><p style='font-size:20px; color:gray; padding:10px; margin:0px; text-align:right;'>Your Email Address: </p></td><td height='20' width='300'><p style='font-size:20px; color:gray; padding:10px; margin:0px;'>$email</p></td></tr>"
                ."<tr><td height='20' width='300'><p style='font-size:20px; color:gray; padding:10px; margin:0px; text-align:right;'>Your Message:</p></td><td height='20' width='300'><p style='font-size:20px; color:gray; padding:0px; margin:10px;'> $message</p></td></tr></table>"
                ."<tr><td colspan='2'  height='15' width='600'><p style=' text-align:center;padding:0px; margin:0px;'><a style='color:#d1502d;font-size:15px;text-align:center;padding:0px; margin:0px;text-decoration:none;'href='http://whimsicalhope.com/testing_hotel_again4/index.html'>Visit Our Site</a></p></td></tr>";

    $mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!';

    if(!$mail->send()) {
        header('location: url');

        } 
    else {
        header('location: url');
      }

   } 
}
```

**Entire Script**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
  <title> Hotel</title>
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style type="text/css">
    .error {
      color:red;
    }
    body {
      padding-top: 146px;
      padding-top:175px;
    }
    .language_choice_english {
      padding-right: 1%
    }

    .language_choice_japanese {
        padding-right: 3%;
    }
  </style>

    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="js/additional-methods.js"></script>
      <script> 
          $(document).ready(function () {

              $('#contactForm').validate({ 
                  ignore: '.no-validation',
                  rules: {
                      email: {
                          required: true,
                          email: true
                      },
                      message: {
                          required: true,
                          minlength: 5                      }, 
                      first_name: {
                        required: true,
                        lettersonly: true, 
                      },
                      last_name: {
                        required: true,
                        lettersonly: true,
                      }
                  }
              });

              $.validator.addMethod("recaptcha", function(value, element) {
                var grecaptcha = window.grecaptcha || null;
                return !grecaptcha || grecaptcha.getResponse();
                }, "Please fill reCAPTCHA");

          });
      </script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<?php
session_start(); //allows use of session variables

if (!isset($_SESSION['token']) && $_SESSION['token'] == $_POST['token']) {

  $token = base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32));
  $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
}

else {
  $token = base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32));
  $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
}

var_dump($_POST, FILE.__LINE__);

?>


  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <a class="brand pull-left" href="index.html">
            <img id="Logo" src="./images/logo_72H.gif" alt="New Hotel">
            </a>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
       <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><span id="overall_title"> Hotel</span><small id="description_of_city">Little Tokyo, Los Angeles, Downtown</small></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="rooms.html">Rooms & information</a></li>
        <li><a href="reserve.php">Book to Reserve</a></li>
        <li><a href="location.html">Location Info</a></li>
        <li><a href="additional.html">Additional Info</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <p class="pull-right language_choice_english"><a href="contact.php">English</a></p>
        <p class="pull-right language_choice_japanese"><a href="contact-ja.php"><span lang="ja">日本語</span></a></p>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<div id="main-container" class="col-xs-12">

  <div>
    <label>* Required fields </label>
  </div>


  <form class="form-horizontal"  method="POST" action="ughAgain.php" id="contactForm">

    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>" />

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="cfirstname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">* First Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input class="form-control"  name="first_name" id="cfirstname" placeholder="First Name" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="clastname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">* Last Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input class="form-control" name="last_name" id="clastname" placeholder="Last Name" type="text">
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="cemail" class="col-sm-2 control-label">* Email</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input class="form-control" name="email" id="cemail" placeholder="Email" type="email">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="cmessage" class="col-sm-2 control-label">* Message</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" placeholder="Please type in your message" name="message" id="cmessage"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey=""></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha" data-rule-recaptcha="true">
  </div>
</div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="Submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>


</div>


 <footer class="col-xs-12 roomsFooter">  

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">2015 Hotel -- All rights reserved</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">Terms of Use</div>
       <div class="col-md-4">Facebook / Twitter / Instagram </div>
    </div>  
  </footer>

  <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Machavity, but my forms are php forms that are using sessions

Comment: That's much better. No more guessing what your forms look like

Comment: @Machavity, glad that helps. Should I post the other form that's near identical just for the heck of it? I mean, the behavior is so consistent. Just different servers, different php versions, but same browser, near same form.

Comment: @RyanVincent, how do I do that?

Comment: @RyanVincent, I added it in the Contact form above to make sure we're on the same page. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @RyanVincent, if yes, this is what I saw in the source code: `array(0) {}
string(6) "FILE78"` for the page that's always showing the form's input.

Comment: @RyanVincent, this is from the other server: `array(0) {} string(6) "FILE79"`

Comment: @RyanVincent, um ... not sure what you quite mean. I have a jquery validation library that makes all fields required before you can submit it.

Comment: @RyanVincent, ok, I did both forms again, submitted it, got redirected, went back via browser's back button, checked the source code in both, and no, I don't see `value=attributes` in either one of them ...

Comment: Ok, it isn't magic. So, the form fields must be being filled from the previous data entered. I suspect it is done via javascript. I have no idea where to go here with the information supplied.

Comment: @RyanVincent, hold on. It can't be done via js. I'm going to put up the entirety of the script to give a more through overview.

Comment: @RyanVincent, have provided the entire script.

Comment: @RyanVincent, ok. thank you so much for trying to help/debug the whole situation. really super appreciate it. truly. happy thursday!

Comment: @RyanVincent, just letting you know that I'm doing `autocomplete="off"` as that seems to keep the form empty when I hit the browser's back button. So, yay? =)

Comment: Glad you got some consistent behaviour. I like that as well. Thanks for the update :)